# Visualizing an AutoDiff MultibodyPlant in PyDrake

Tags: visualization, drake

I am trying to build a simple multibody plant system in [Drake](https://drake.mit.edu/) using the basic `DrakeVisualizer`. However, for my use case, I also want to be able to automatically track the derivatives through the physics simulation, so am using the AutoDiffXd version of system:

```
timestep = 1e-3
builder = DiagramBuilder_[AutoDiffXd]()

plant = MultibodyPlant(timestep)
scene_graph = SceneGraph_[AutoDiffXd]()

brick_file = FindResourceOrThrow("drake/examples/manipulation_station/models/061_foam_brick.sdf")
parser = Parser(plant)
brick = parser.AddModelFromFile(brick_file, model_name="brick")

plant.Finalize()
plant_ad = plant.ToAutoDiffXd()
plant_ad.RegisterAsSourceForSceneGraph(scene_graph)

scene_graph.AddRenderer("renderer", MakeRenderEngineVtk(RenderEngineVtkParams()))
DrakeVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph)

builder.AddSystem(plant_ad)
builder.AddSystem(scene_graph)
builder.Connect(plant_ad.get_geometry_poses_output_port(), scene_graph.get_source_pose_port(plant_ad.get_source_id()))
builder.Connect(scene_graph.get_query_output_port(), plant_ad.get_geometry_query_input_port())

diagram = builder.Build()
context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
simulator = Simulator_[AutoDiffXd](diagram, context)
simulator.AdvanceTo(2.0)
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/craig/Repos/drake-exps/autoDiffExperiment.py", line 102, in auto_phys
    DrakeVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph)
TypeError: AddToBuilder(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (builder: pydrake.systems.framework.DiagramBuilder_[float], scene_graph: drake::geometry::SceneGraph<double>, lcm: pydrake.lcm.DrakeLcmInterface = None, params: pydrake.geometry.DrakeVisualizerParams = <pydrake.geometry.DrakeVisualizerParams object at 0x7ff6274e14b0>) -> pydrake.geometry.DrakeVisualizer
    2. (builder: pydrake.systems.framework.DiagramBuilder_[float], query_object_port: pydrake.systems.framework.OutputPort_[float], lcm: pydrake.lcm.DrakeLcmInterface = None, params: pydrake.geometry.DrakeVisualizerParams = <pydrake.geometry.DrakeVisualizerParams object at 0x7ff627736730>) -> pydrake.geometry.DrakeVisualizer

Invoked with: <pydrake.systems.framework.DiagramBuilder_[AutoDiffXd] object at 0x7ff65654f8f0>, <pydrake.geometry.SceneGraph_[AutoDiffXd] object at 0x7ff656562130>
```

From this error, it appears the DrakeVisualizer class only accepts systems which use float scalars exlusively. So I am stuck --- either I can go back to floats (but lose the autodiff differentiable simulation functionality I was after in the first place), or continue to use autodiffxd systems (but be completely unable to visualize what is going on in my simulation).

Is there a way to get both that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the pain and inconvenience. Your description and assessment are all spot on. Most of the visualization mechanisms are `float` only and, in its current state, attempts to visualizing an `AutoDiff` diagram will fail.

You have a couple of options (neither of which is appealing):

1. Go with one of the outcomes you've described above (no vis or no derivatives).
2. Put in a Drake feature request to be able to attach a visualizer to an `AutoDiff` diagram.

I can come up with some hacky workarounds (that aren't immediately clear would even work). So, if you're desperate for derivatives and visualization, they could be explored. But, ultimately, the feature request and a formal Drake solution would be the best long-term resolution.

=====================================

Big update. As of [#14569](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/14569), the `DrakeVisualizer` class is now templated on the scalar type (item 2 in the list above). That has two implications:

1. You can build an `AutoDiffXd`-valued diagram with a visualizer in it (as in your example), or
2. You can create a `double`-valued diagram and scalar convert it (i.e., `diagram.ToAutoDiffXd()` into an `AutoDiffXd`-valued diagram.

Comment: FWIW I believe my suggestion in [#13074](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13074#issuecomment-630926022) may make it easier to make option (1) work (which IMO is the best solution; visualizing via AutoDiff seems like a waste of object code). Most specifically, it would be related to this workflow: [code](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/3d297d22117941d773a954547fc47f673987a111/drake_stuff/multibody_plant_prototypes/multibody_plant_subgraph.py#L34-L38)

Comment: I would have answered differently.  I agree that you need `float` for visualization, and also autodiff, but probably you don't actually need them at the same time (we don't support differentiable rendering/visualization).

So without any new features, you can create an autodiff diagram without visualization, run optimization (e.g. find a trajectory), then construct the diagram in float for visualization.  That sounds frustrating, but in most cases we don't actually autodiff through an entire `Simulator`, but hand an autodiff plant/diagram to some other method (like trajectory optimization).